# How to speed up iteration over part of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large 3 dimensional array in numpy (lets say size 100x100x100). I'd like to iterate over just parts of it many times (approx 70% of elements) and I have a boolean matrix that is the same size and defines whether the element should have the operation done or not.

My current method is to first to create an array "coords" of shape (N,3) which contains all the coords on which to do the operation and then

```
for i in np.arange(many_iterations):
    for j in coords:
        large_array[j] = do_something(large_array[tuple(j)])
```

Would it in fact be better to evaluate the whole array and include an extra operation in the loop to test the boolean array (bear in mind that the truth evaluation is then done many_iterations times rather than once). My thought was that the pay off in this case would be getting rid of the for loops

```
large_array = do_something(large_array if condition True)
```

How would this last line be made to work in this case?

Comment: Depending on what `do_something` is, you might be able to do `large_array[boolean_array] = do_something(large_array[boolean_array])`, or something shorter still.

Comment: I think your sentiment is right, it might be to your benefit to do the operation on the whole array and then use something like`numpy.where`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might get better performance by first creating an array of booleans that define where you should operate:

```
big_3d_arr = some 100x100x100 array
where_to_operate_arr = big_3d_arr < 500 # or whatever your condition is
big_3d_arr[where_to_operate_arr] = do_something(big_3d_arr[where_to_operate_arr])
```

Something like that might work, but again you may have to iterate and do the boolean indexing in chunks, depending on your application.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed. do_something is a function that gets each element of the array and makes it the average of its surrounding elements (to do that I'm copying the array and then using a series of np.roll to offset the array and add). I decided against masks in the end since I'm still using the masked data and it seemed a bit more complicated than this solution.

Answer (score 3):

You're basically trying to recreate [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html). [This](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) page gives a good introduction.